# How to run testng.xml file from jenkins on mac

Tags: gradle, testng

Mac doesn't support batch file? What is the alternative, how we can run testng.xml file from jenkins. I'm using gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

try to create .sh file instead of bat file

java -cp "path-tojar/testng.jar:path_to_yourtest_classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: Getting error : [TestNG] [ERROR] 
Cannot find class in classpath: "ClassName".